# GCS file getting moved before processing with and without async calls

Tags: c#, async-await, google-cloud-storage

I have written the following code that is called within an API running in Cloud Run. This API gets called once for each file that gets created in a GCS bucket via pubsub notification. Today I added code for moving the file to processed or failed buckets depending on whether my files got processed completely or not. However, looking at my StackDriver logs it seems that in a lot of cases, the file gets deleted from the incoming folder and moved to processed before the rest of the code has had a chance to read it. I will see a line saying beginning to read file xyz, but then right after it would throw an error because the file got moved. My code originally was not using async and await and even then I was seeing same behaviour. Any idea why this is happening? I can attach StackDriver logs if it helps.

```
        private async Task ReadMyFile(MyFile file)
        {
            FileStream downloadStream= null;
            StorageClient storageClient = StorageClient.Create();
            try
            {
                var gcsURI = @"gs://" + file.bucket + @"/" + file.fileName;
                Console.WriteLine("Beginning to Read My File: " + gcsURI); 
                using (downloadStream= System.IO.File.Create(file.fileName))
                {
                    storageClient.DownloadObject(file.bucket, file.fileName, downloadStream);
                    downloadStream.Position = 0;
                }
                using (var f = System.IO.File.OpenRead(file.fileName))
                using (var zip = new ZipArchive(f, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
                using (var stream = zip.Entries[0].Open())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully downloaded My File: " + gcsURI);
                    var fna = GetFileAttributesFromFileName(file.fileName);

                    int type1Counter = 0;
                    int type2Counter = 0;
                    int type3Counter = 0;
                    StringBuilder type1s = new StringBuilder();
                    StringBuilder type2s = new StringBuilder();
                    StringBuilder type3Points = new StringBuilder();

                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            var tokens = line.Split(',');
                            int dataType = Convert.ToInt32(tokens[1]);
                            int oid = Convert.ToInt32(tokens[0]);
                            DateTime dateTimeUTC = Convert.ToDateTime(tokens[2]);
                            switch (dataType)
                            {
                                case 0:
                                    var type1Line = taName + "|" + bt + "|" + fna.vId + "|" + fna.dd + "|" + dateTimeUTC.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "|" + dateTimeUTC.ToString("HH") + "|" + line.Replace(",", "|");
                                    type1s.AppendLine(type1Line);
                                    type1Counter++;
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    var type2Line = taName + "|" + bt + "|" + fna.vId + "|" + fna.dd + "|" + dateTimeUTC.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "|" + dateTimeUTC.ToString("HH") + "|" + line.Replace(",", "|");
                                    type2s.AppendLine(type2Line);
                                    type2Counter++;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    var type3_Line = taName + "|" + bt + "|" + fna.vId + "|" + fna.dd + "|" + dateTimeUTC.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "|" + dateTimeUTC.ToString("HH") + "|" + line.Replace(",", "|");
                                    type3Points.AppendLine(type3_Line);
                                    type3Counter++;
                                    break;
                                detype1:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (type1Counter > 0)
                    {
                        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
                        {
                            writer.Write(type1s);
                            writer.Flush();
                            memoryStream.Position = 0;

                            await storageClient.UploadObjectAsync
                                (file.readyforingestionbucket,
                                "f_" + file.fileName,
                                "text/plain",
                                memoryStream);
                        }
                    }

                    if (type2Counter > 0)
                    {
                        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
                        {
                            writer.Write(type2s);
                            writer.Flush();
                            memoryStream.Position = 0;

                            await storageClient.UploadObjectAsync
                                (file.readyforingestionbucket,
                                "n_" + file.fileName,
                                "text/plain",
                                memoryStream);
                        }
                    }

                    if (type3Counter > 0)
                    {
                        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
                        {
                            writer.Write(type3Points);
                            writer.Flush();
                            memoryStream.Position = 0;

                            await storageClient.UploadObjectAsync
                                (file.readyforingestionbucket,
                                "a_" + file.fileName,
                                "text/plain",
                                memoryStream);
                        }
                    }

                    // File completed processing, move to processed folder
                    Console.WriteLine("Copying {0} to processed folder {1}", file.fileName, file.processedBucket);
                    await storageClient.CopyObjectAsync(file.bucket, file.fileName, file.processedBucket, file.fileName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Copied {0} to processed folder {1}", file.fileName, file.processedBucket);
                    Console.WriteLine("Deleting {0}", file.fileName);
                    await storageClient.DeleteObjectAsync(file.bucket, file.fileName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Deleted {0}", file.fileName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error reading file: " + file.fileName + " - " + ex.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.ToString());

                // File failed processing, move to failed folder
                Console.WriteLine("Copying {0} to failed folder {1}", file.fileName, file.failedbucket);
                var copied = storageClient.CopyObjectAsync(file.bucket, file.fileName, file.failedbucket, file.fileName);
                copied.Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Copied {0} to processed folder {1}", file.fileName, file.failedbucket);
                Console.WriteLine("Deleting {0}", file.fileName);
                storageClient.DeleteObject(file.bucket, file.fileName);
                Console.WriteLine("Deleted {0}", file.fileName);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    downloadStream.Dispose();
                    // Delete the file to not run out of disk space on the image.
                    Console.Write("Deleting local file from image: " + file.fileName);
                    System.IO.File.Delete(file.fileName);
                    Console.Write("Deleted local file from image: " + file.fileName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error deleting file: " + file.fileName);
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is a *debugging problem*, you should *log* this heavily (every line you are not sure about), and workout what its actually doing. Asking us to *debug* it is not really what SO is intended for

Comment: In the logs I am seeing files getting copied and deleted before the rest of the code. I dont see why that is. Should it not wait at await storageClient.UploadObjectAsync call? I think I have coded this properly yet not seeing the behaviour. That's not a debugging problem. Or I guess everything is.